# Router no Zend 1.12 ocultar controller e action

Tags: php, htaccess, zend

Olá, quero fazer com que o usuario não veja meu controller e nem o action no ZF 1.12.

Ex:

```
 http://meusite.com/produtos/listar/item/iphone-5s-preto
```

Quero que fique assim:

```
 http://meusite.com/iphone-5s-preto.html
```

Não precisa nem ter o .html basta ficar o nome do produto direto ou que pelo menos nao apareça o action, pode ficar só o controller. Quero é deixar a url o minimo possivel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note que eu não entendo nada de Zend, eu fiz apenas uma breve leitura da documentação, pode conter erros

Eu não sei como está o seu sistema (se as rotas são "automatizadas"), mas você poderia tentar reescreve-las usando `addRoute` e `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex`, por exemplo:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    '([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.html',
    array(
        'controller' => 'archive',
        'action'     => 'show'
    )
);
$router->addRoute('archive', $route);
```

Se você preferir usar um sistema de rotas por diretorio (parece o seu caso), você terá que definir uma url tipo esta `/produto/nome-do-produto.html` e usar `setControllerDirectory`

```
$ctrl->setControllerDirectory(
    array(
        'produto' => '/produtos/listar/item/controllers',
        'blog'    => '/path/to/blog/controllers'
    )
);
```